# Is destructuring assignment guaranteed to be parallel assignment in Swift?

Tags: swift, assignment-operator, destructuring

I'm looking at [the description of the assignment operator](https://docs.swift.org/swift-book/ReferenceManual/Expressions.html#grammar_assignment-operator) in the Swift language reference. Is it guaranteed that destructuring assignment is made in parallel? As opposed to serial assignment. I don't see that point addressed in the description of the assignment operator.

Just to be clear, is it guaranteed that `(a, b) = (b, a)` (where `a` and `b` are `var`) is equivalent to `foo = a`, `a = b`, `b = foo`, where `foo` is a variable which is guaranteed not to exist yet, and not `a = b`, `b = a` (which would yield `a` and `b` both with the same value). I tried `(a, b) = (b, a)` and it appears to work in parallel, but that's not the same as a documented description of the behavior.

Comment: "but that's not the same as a documented description of the behavior." Well, the documentation did not mention it, so you can't say it's not "the same". There are many things the docs don't say, unfortunately. And since the docs don't say, I would call it an "implementation detail" of the swift compiler.

Comment: @Sweeper As far as I understand, OP is asking if it's possible for this assignment to happen in a way that causes `a` to clobber `b` or vice versa. If that's the case, that's an important matter of language semantics, far from just an implementation detail.

Comment: "I tried (a, b) = (b, a) and it appears to work in parallel, but that's not the same as a documented description of the behavior." Which "documented description of behaviour" do you think is being contradicted? Are you referring to the sentence "Assignment is performed from each part of the value to the corresponding part of the expression."?

Comment: @Alexander I know, but the documentation doesn't say anything about whether the clobbering will happen. Therefore, it is an implementation detail, in the sense that it's  up to the compiler to decide what to do with an assignment. I could theoretically write a compiler that works almost like `swiftc`, except that it does assignment in sequence, and still call it a "Swift Compiler" because it does what the reference says.

Comment: @Alexander The observed behavior is consistent with my expectation that destructuring assignment would be executed in parallel. What I was saying is that a stated documentation for that behavior would be preferable to inferring it from the observed result of an experiment.

Comment: @Sweeper Not really, since Swift doesn't have a standardized language specification. I think the main compiler's implementation is a more authoritative language spec than the introductory language book. Should the two conflict, I would default to taking the compiler's interpretation to be the more "authoritative one". All that is to say, I would write code like `(b, a) = (a, b)` without blinking, and I would be very very surprised if the compiler implementation on something so significant changed.

Comment: @Alexander Well, I would be surprised too. I wish Swift were standardised, just like C#, Java, and JS...

Comment: @Sweeper Are you sure you really want that? 1) Not having a language committee and spec makes you able to move waaaaaay faster, 2) There are only two implementations of Swift (that I know of, the Swift.org one, and the Silver Elements Compiler), so there's little need to synchronize many independently working teams, unlike JS (which has dozens of implementations) and such.

Comment: @RobertDodier "destructuring assignment would be executed in parallel." Not actually. All you've observed is that it doesn't happen in a clobbering way. For all you know, there's `foo_a` and `foo_b` used to store the independent original values of `a` and `b`, which are then assigned to `b` and `a` respectively.

Comment: @RobertDodier  "What I was saying is that a stated documentation for that behavior would be preferable to inferring it from the observed result of an experiment." Ohhh, I see. I misread "not the same as ***a*** documented description of the behavior." as "not the same as the documented description of the behavior.", which has a very different meaning :)

Comment: @Alexander I feel like our discussion is going off-topic from the question here, so I'll stop...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tuples are value types, and once constructed they are independent of the values that are part of them.

```swift
var a = 2
var b = 3
var t1 = (a, b)
print(t1) // (2, 3)
a = 4
print(t1) // (2, 3)
```

Thus the tuple `(a, b)` carries the actual values of the two variables, which is why the `(b, a) = (a, b)` assignment works without problems. Behind the scenes, the actual assigment is `(b, a) = (2, 3)` (assuming `a` and `b` have the values from the above code snippet).